# How to make a hover menu bar?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a hover menu bar in CSS? So if I go with my mouse over home, that informatica, hobby and ik will pop up.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="menu-bar">
 <nav>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Informatica</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Hobby</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Ik</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 </nav>
 </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: sorry @Ryon M we're going to need a little more information about what you're trying to achieve to be able to help you? Do you have an example?

Comment: Also note that your HTML is slightly incorrect. You have closed the parent `li` twice...and not closed the overall `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

ul ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu-bar">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Informatica</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hobby</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ik</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/8ccL5duf/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this css:

```
ul>li{
  display:none;
}

ul:hover li{
  display:block;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paxrs796/)

Answer (score 0):

try this may help

```
<div class="menu">
<nav>
<ul id="menu-bar">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Informatica</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hobby</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ik</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

and in style

```
<style>
#menu-bar li ul
{
display:none;
}
#menu-bar li:hover ul
{
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It is always useful to post demo (jsfiddle or codepen) link together with your code :)